# Magento From local server to live web server, links not working

Tags: magento

Now, the homepage is working fine but every link on it directs you to a 404 not found error. Can't even access "/admin".

Comment: provide a link of your website

Comment: http://www.learnmagento.org/magento-tips-tricks/magento-fix-404-found-error-magento-frontend/

Answer (score -1):

Just add **"index.php"** next to the domain. For ex: If your website name is **www.google.com** then try to access this as **www.google.com/index.php/electronics/cell-phones.html**

This is due to the url rewrite in magento.

Permanent solution: Go to the admin and follow this:

System-> Configuration -> **Web** ->**Search engine Optimization** -> **Url Web Server Rewrites**. Make this to **YES** and **SAVE** the changes.

Now clear the cache and navigate to all the page in your website.

Comment: For the person who made this down vote; Are you sure this is not the correct answer for this? Give me the reason by comment for why you downvoted this?